# Postfix corrupting Japanese characters

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, exim, japanese, mta

I'm having a problem with certain Japanese characters being corrupted when sent by my MTA, Postfix.

I've done some trial and error sending the same message from approx 7 different servers running CentOS, Ubuntu, Mac OS X and Debian.  In every event the mail failed except for two instances where the MTA appeared to be Exim.

Since the mail seems to be corrupted regardless of OS but always with Postfix, I am deducing that Postfix is the culprit. The odd thing is it deals with 99% of the characters fine but ends up corrupting only a couple.

Can anyone make a suggestion about where things might possibly be going wrong?  Is it possible that this is a bug in Postfix itself or are there special config requirements for dealing with certain Japanese characters?

EDIT: Here's a cample of the text and how it gets changed.  I've included the entire snippet since, oddly, the problem only seems to arise when this whole block is included.  If I take the first or second half alone it gets sent fine.

`中学、高校と６年間皆勤賞を貰うほど健康だった私が、高校卒業直前に訪れたシンガポールから帰国して１週間後に高熱が出て病院に運ばれました。ただの風邪だと判断し、注射で熱を下げてから数日後、体全身の痛みで寝返りもうてず、車椅子にのる。おばあさんが私の横を小走りで通り過ぎて行ったのを見て涙が出たのを覚えています。膝に水が溜まるようになり、溜まっては抜いてを繰り返し、また全身に痛みがあるということで膠原病内科に入院。先生に原因不明だと言われ、痛み止めのみを処方され３ヶ月、、途方に暮れていた時に、ステロイド治療を勧められどうしても同意できずに退院することにしました。病名がないので薬がないから痛み止めしか出せないと言われ、これからどうなってしまうの`

gets changed to:

`中学、高校と６年間皆勤賞を貰うほど健康だった私が、高校卒業直前に訪れたシンガポールから帰国して１週間後に高熱が出て病院に運ばれました。ただの風邪だと判断し、注射で熱を下げてから数日後、体全身の痛みで寝返りもうてず、車椅子にのる。おばあさんが私の横を小走りで通り過ぎて行ったのを見て涙が出たのを覚えています。膝に水が溜まるようになり、溜まっては抜いてを繰り返し、また全身に痛みがあるということで膠原病内科に入院。先生に原因不明だと言われ、痛み止めのみを処方され３ヶ月、、途方に暮れていた時に、ステロイド治療を勧められどうしても同意できずに退院することにしました。病名がないので薬がない� �ら痛み止めしか出せないと言われ、これからどうなってしまうの`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the Japanese text and identify the characters that are affected and what they get changed to? It sounds like a problem with detection or handling of encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  Base64 encode message before handing it to postfix.  Doesn't seem like this should be necessary but it works. Note, base64 does not get rid of missing characters but does prevent the entire msg from getting scrambled when viewed on mobile devices.